# Adding value/object in IpagedList

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, pagination

```
public ActionResult View()
{
    List<user> user= sql.display().ToList();
    user.Add(new{user});
    return View(user);
}
```

I need pagination so i modified this code in this way :

```
using PagedList;
using PagedList.Mvc;
public ActionResult View(int? page)
{
    IPagedList<user> user= sql.display().ToPagedList(page ?? 1,2);
    // how do i add object in user now
    return View(user);
}
```

If it was a list i would have easily used Add method but i cannot use in IpagedList . So how can i add object user in IpagedList user.

Comment: Create your list, add the new user and then generate the PagedList from that list - `IPagedList<user> u = user.ToPagedList(...)`

Comment: Thanks, lol quite dumb question eventually . :D THanks it worked

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult View(int? page)
{
         List<user> user = sql.display().ToList();
         user.Add(new user());
         IPagedList<user> user1= user.ToPagedList(page ?? 1,2);
         return View(user1);
}
```

SOlution,